# Extract a zip file to your own directory

Tags: linux, shell, zip

Im trying to extract the contents of a zip file but I want to extract it to my own directory.

I'v tried `-d` from unzip but that just puts the contents of the zip into that directory.

But I want to extract the contents of the first (root) directory in the zip if there is only one directory in the root of the zip else just extract the files/folders in the root of the zip file (if there are more then one files).

e.g.
`test.zip` contents the following dir structure:

```
test.zip
  \
 /app_v1/ <-The contents of this directory I want extracted to a dir of my choice
      \
     - folder-1
     - folder-2
     - folder-3
     - folder-4
     - file1
     - file2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to combine `-j` with `-d`. `-j` lets you junk the paths that are there. Mind you, if there're other folders you don't want, they'll get lumped in too.

```
unzip -jd <some_path> test.zip
```

Comment: this flatten the directory structure, everything will be in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

or you can use the most flexible

```
unzip -p zipfile.zip some/path/file.txt > otherfilename.txt
```

This way you can even immediately do whatever it was you wanted to with it without having to save it, if that's only a temporary file, e.g.

```
unzip -p zipfile.zip some/path/file.iso | md5sum
```